# Sequelize - Nested wheres overriding eachother

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Considering this request (ran against Postgres)

```
var customers = await database.Customer.findAll({
    attributes: [ 'idcustomer', 'firstname', 'lastname' ],
    include: [
        { 
             model: database.Telephone, as: "Telephones", 
             attributes: [ 'number' ], 
             where: { number: { [database.sequelize.Op.eq]: req.body.telephone } } 
        }
    ],
    where: { [database.sequelize.Op.or]: [
        { firstname: { [database.sequelize.Op.iLike]: req.body.firstname} },
        { lastname: { [database.sequelize.Op.iLike]: req.body.lastname} },
        { email: { [database.sequelize.Op.iLike]: req.body.email } }
    ] }
});
```

What i'm trying to achieve is query for customers by first&last name/email/telephone number, let's call them F, L, E and T. This query basically selects all users where T & (F | L | E), however, what I'm trying to get to is (F | L | E | T).

The bottom where parameter in the code filters prepends "Customer." to the parameters so grouping the number with the rest of the comparisons is not possible. Is there a workaround for this?

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
   "Customer"."idcustomer", "Customer"."firstname", "Customer"."lastname",
   "Telephones"."number" AS "Telephones.number"
FROM "Customer" AS "Customer"
INNER JOIN "Telephone" AS "Telephones" 
    ON "Customer"."idcustomer" = "Telephones"."customer" AND "Telephones"."number" = ''
WHERE
   ("Customer"."firstname" ILIKE '' OR "Customer"."lastname" ILIKE '' OR "Customer"."email" ILIKE '');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Sequelize.col() to reference the included row :

```
var customers = await database.Customer.findAll({
    attributes: [ 'idcustomer', 'firstname', 'lastname' ],
    include: [
        { 
            model: database.Telephone, 
            as: "Telephones", 
            attributes: [ 'number' ]
        }
    ],
    where: { [database.sequelize.Op.or]: [
        {
          telephone: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.col(`"Telephones".number`), {
            [database.sequelize.Op.eq]: req.body.telephone
          })
        },
        { firstname: { [database.sequelize.Op.iLike]: req.body.firstname} },
        { lastname: { [database.sequelize.Op.iLike]: req.body.lastname} },
        { email: { [database.sequelize.Op.iLike]: req.body.email } }
    ] }
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry Philippe, the generated SQL was already an INNER JOIN, I've added it to the initial question. What i'm looking to do is basically move the phone number statement with the others in the OR clause. (perhaps as an Op.contains)

Comment: dont be sorry, I definitely read your question way too fast. Gonna update asap.

Comment: @5unkEn I updated my answer, sorry about the time lost.